# Java call main() method of a class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I need to call the main method of a Java class from another main method using reflection.

Usage of reflection is a must so as to remove compile time dependency of the main class being called.
Straightforward approach is not yielding as it recognizes only 'public' and 'non-static' method.
Suggestions?

Comment: Calling a static method via reflection shouldn't be any more complicated than calling a non-static one. Can you post your code, so we can tell what's going wrong?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Shouldn't be any more complicated than calling any other function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("pkg1.pkg2.classname");
    Method meth = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    String[] params = null; // init params accordingly
    meth.invoke(null, (Object) params); // static method doesn't have an instance
}
```

But I don't really see many uses for that, the only thing it buys you is that you can compile the program without linking the other one as long as you never use that specific code path, but if that's what you need, here we go ;)

Comment: Thks...fr ur time & answer. I had messed up the code by reading the name of the class thru a property file and had made an error while passing the parameter. Once I corrected them indeed I was able to call....

Comment: while invoking the method why we need to typecast params to Object, when main method is expects String[] and we are passing exactly the same type. I tried without typecasting but it does not work. Any idea why we need to do this.

Comment: @Bagira `invoke` expects an `Object[]` (`Object...` is just syntax for that) containing all parameters to the method. We only want to pass it one parameter a string array. The problem is that arrays in java are covariant (i.e. `String[] p; Object[] o = p` will compile without any problems), hence if we just pass it a single string array that is interpreted as the object array, so the method thinks you're passing it several strings and not one string array.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE TO EVERYONE: The key thing to notice in this answer is the cast of params to Object! It's essential! See the comment above.

Comment: The above almost worked. The value assigned to params cannot be 'null'. (Main() is entitled to test the length of the args array.) The value assigned must be 'new String[0]'.

Comment: For old version Java (such as 1.5). You need use: Method mth = clazz.getMethod("main", new Class[] {String[].class});

Answer (score 0):

```
Method mainMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
final Object[] args = new Object[1];
args[0] = new String[]{"1", "2"};
mainMethod.invoke(null, args);
```