# Call a class from another class without having to change the class type (or the return) Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, program-entry-point

I am trying to run a class from another class. But it asks me to change the type when I store the class name in an array. I want the user to enter a number which would be fed into the array and run the class at that array value. 
Here is my code so far:

```
public class All_Challenges {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Which class do you want to run?: ");
    System.out.println("1. The first class");

Class[] theFiles = new Class[31];
    theFiles[1] = Challenge_1_Whats_Your_Name.main(args);
    theFiles[1].main(args);
    }
}
```

The last two lines are giving me an error because they are making me change the class type from The `void` to type `class` and then making add a `return statement`. I have around 30 of these so I would prefer not to have to change my main method in all my other classes. What stuff should I write so that I don't have to do this. I think it's something to do with what "type" my array is. Or maybe it's to do with the line `main.(args);` 
Weird part is that it doesn't ask me to change the type when I don't call it from an array.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - why are you creating an array at all? What do you expect to do with it?

Comment: Typically the JVM calls the `main()` method on your behalf, rather than you directly.  Can you let us know what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: you are assigning a `void` which is the result of calling `main(args)` into a variable (whatever it is) instance of object of type `Class` or any other variable, you can't because `void` can't be set as a value. what you need to do is (may be) store the class in that array, and use `reflection` to instantiate it and call a certain method. unless you clarify more what you want to do.

Comment: You cannot invoke the static methods of a class directly on the `Class` object representing that class.  If a `Class` is your only handle on the class of interest, then you must use reflection to invoke its static methods.

Comment: or just use an `Interface`

Comment: And you do not ordinarily obtain a `Class` instance by invoking (one of) the corresponding class's `main()` method(s), if it even has any.  If you know the class's name statically, then you can use a class literal, e.g. `Challenge_1_Whats_Your_Name.class`.  Otherwise, you need to obtain the `Class` reflectively.

Comment: I can manually input the class name. But I do not want to change the main method in each of those classes. The only thing I need is an array to be able to do this. I think making the array of a certain type will not make me change the main method in the classes.

Comment: "The only thing I need is an array to be able to do this." *Why*? You still haven't explained why you believe you need an array at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to put a method to array of classes.

```
    Class[] theFiles = new Class[31];
    theFiles[1] = Challenge_1_Whats_Your_Name.class;
    try {
        theFiles[1].getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(args);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That should work for you

Comment: This doesn't run the `Challenge_1_Whats_Your_Name` program in this class though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using reflections:

```
public class TestMain {

    private static final Class<?>[] classArray = {A.class, B.class};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Class<?> classExec : classArray) {
            try {
                //get main
                Method method = classExec.getMethod("main", String[].class);
                method.invoke(null, (Object) args);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class A {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }   

}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4980149/1255493